# django: using Q to filter taking into account blank choice scenario

Tags: python, mysql, django

There are 2 criteria in the form entered and submitted by user to filter the database. Because user might leave these two blank, so I made some scenarios. If it is left blank, then in database no need to filter by this constraint.

The default value is "None".

This is the post that I referenced: [django conditionally filtering objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651211/django-conditionally-filtering-objects)

I tried 2 ways , neither works, hope someone could help:

**First way**

```
if criteria_1 is None and criteria_2 !=None: return Q(criteria_2=criteria_2)
elif criteria_2 is None and criteria_1 !=None: return Q(criteria_1=criteria_1)
elif criteria_1 !=None and criteria_2 !=None: return Q(criteria_2=criteria_2,criteria_1=criteria_1)
elif criteria_1 is None and criteria_2 is None: return Q()
else: return Q()

queryset=XXX.objects.filter(Q,date_new__range=[start_date,end_date])
```

**Second way**

```
only_criteria_1_none=Q(criteria_1__isnull=True)
only_criteria_2_none=Q(criteria_2__isnull=True)
both_selected=Q(criteria_1=criteria_1,criteria_2=criteria_2)
both_none=Q(criteria_1__isnull=True,criteria_2__isnull=True)
```

queryset=XXX.objects.filter(only_criteria_1_none|only_criteria_2_none|both_selected|both_none)

**Method 3 ---EDIT**

forms.py

```
iquery = XXX.objects.values_list('region', flat=True).distinct()
iquery_choices = [('', '')] + [(region,region)  for region in iquery]
region = forms.ChoiceField(choices=iquery_choices,required=False,widget=forms.Select())
```

-----same for country------the default value is ""

views.py

```
if country =="" and region !="":
    queryset=XXX.objects.filter(country,date_new__range=[start_date,end_date])
if region ="" and country !="":
    queryset=XXX.objects.filter(region,date_new__range=[start_date,end_date])
。。。。。。。。。。
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you need to use `Q` at all, django's query sets are done so lazily so it isn't ran until you actually need the results..

```
queryset = Foo.objects.filter(base_query_stuff)
if bar_criteria:
     queryset = queryset.filter(bar_stuff)
if cheese_criteria:
     queryset = queryset.filter(cheese_stuff)

return queryset
```

This makes your query look much easier to understand.

Comment: ,thanks for the reply. When you put "bar_criteria", do you mean by this criteria is not blank and another is blank? I think I need to elaborate more on my case, because your answer seems to simply my question. The 2 fields could be left blank, so there are 4 scenarios in total. And there is a 3rd field that is necessary to fill. That's why I want to use Q to make it clearer.

Comment: @Elena - Yes the criterias in your example are if they aren't blank, with most forms I use if the field is blank then they are not included in the `POST` data but thats still kind of irrelevant I guess. Basically what I am saying is whatever you choose warrants the inclusion of different fields should be used to modify the query with different filters.

Comment: thanks. I updated the answer as you suggest. This time it doesn't report any error, but the filter doesn't work if I leave any field blank. I set the default value as 'None‘ in forms.py. In views.py, the "if" condition is to judge if it is "None" or not. Do you think if there is anything wrong in my updated code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Elena - You'll need to step through with a debugger and figure out what your conditions are doing

Comment: I have found the problem. I shouldn't use "is None", instead I should use "  =="" ". Thanks.