# Django, how the conditional queries works?

Tags: python, django

I have a question, I think is very basic but I didn't find answer for this.
Based in the thread [django conditionally filtering objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651211/django-conditionally-filtering-objects)

Using the same example:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
category = Category.objects.get(pk=1)
qs = Item.objects.filter(user=user, date=now())
if category:
    qs = qs.filter(category=category)
```

When the `qs` variable retrieve the results? 
Because, if the line `Item.objects.filter(user=user, date=now())` gives as result 1 million of records (after filter the category), those records will be loaded in memory? Or the queries are retrieving the information at the same time of the `render view` (or whatever method I would use) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you read official Django documentation regarding [retrieving objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects)

Django QuerySet is [lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) and executed when data is evaluated

> QuerySets are lazy – the act of creating a QuerySet doesn’t involve
>   any database activity. You can stack filters together all day long,
>   and Django won’t actually run the query until the QuerySet is
>   evaluated.

For example, if you do

```
print(qs)
```

you'll actually evaluate your qs and trigger database select and map data to QuerySet